# Django-filter for nullable Boolean Field

Tags: django, boolean, django-filter

I would like to use `django-filter` for `BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)`. When I use it out of the box, the form generates three options: Unknown (no filtering), Yes (`True`) and No (`False`). However, I need a fourth option for `None` so that the filter specifically selects those records with value `None`.

**My model (relevant part)**:

```
class Record(Model):
    accepted = BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Accepted?"))
```

**My filter (relevant part)**:

```
class RecordFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = OrderedDict((
            ("accepted", ["exact"]),
        ))
```

**My view**:

```
class RecordList(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = Record
    paginate_by = 25
    template_name = "record/record_list.html"
    filterset_class = RecordFilter
```

**My template (relevant part)**:

```
<form method="get" role="form" class="form">
      {{ filter.form.as_p }}
      <button>{% trans "Filter" %}</button>
</form>
```

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by constructing a `ChoiceFilter` with the correct arguments, as a user demonstrated [here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/522#issuecomment-258171253).

That said, the framework should fully support `NullBooleanField`s, and I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/1012) to resolve this.

Comment: Looks like a solution, but AFAIK, Django's `NullBooleanField` is deprecated in favor of `BooleanField(null=True)`. Might this be a problem?

Comment: Good point. That said - it shouldn't matter in the short term. The `ChoiceFilter` solution should work for both cases just fine.